# Can i use multiple function in SoapClient::__soapCall using SOAP API in PHP

Tags: php, soap

I want to call multiple functions in `__soapCall()` methods. I have WSDL file and use the SOAP client.

```
<?php
$client  =   new \SoapClient("http://www.holidaywebservice.com/Holidays/US/USHolidayService.asmx?wsdl");
$functionArr = ["GetHolidaysAvailable","GetHolidaysForMonth"];
$countries = $client->__soapCall($functionArr,[]);
?>
```

I am unable to call/add multiple functions using __soapCall().

Or any have method to get data from multiple functions/methods using soap client in php.?

Expected result:

I want to achieve both all holidays and monthly holidays(response of multiple functions).

Comment: add your expected result, what you want to do

Comment: @SagarPPanchal i am unable to call multiple function in __soapCall() can we call multiple functions using soap through WSDL?

Comment: Each SoapCall is an http request in the end, so at one point, each call has to be make on its own. I am not sure if php soap adds this helper to summarize. Yet I would map that functionArray and call each one on its own and merge the result arrays. Why is it important for it to be at once? Do you want to parallize those calls? (BTW: not really possible through php)

Comment: Furthermore, in your example soap service the soap action [`GetHolidaysForMonth`](http://www.holidaywebservice.com/Holidays/US/USHolidayService.asmx?op=GetHolidaysForMonth) is parameterized and wouldn't work as you intend to. What do you want to achieve?

Comment: @k0pernikus I want to achieve monthly and all available holidays

Comment: @k0pernikus did you understand?

Comment: No, I didn't. I don't understand how you want to consume the soap service and why you want to do it that way. What's your desired result?

Comment: @k0pernikus actually i want to get data of multiple functions using wsdl file in soap api.when we pass one function it's return data of one function when i pass multiple function it should return data of multiple functions.clear?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164698/discussion-between-raheel-aslam-and-k0pernikus).